# Solving a 2 variable integral with a delta function

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

How can this integrals that include the dirac delta function be solved?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dq\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dp\cdot p^n\cdot \delta(p^2+q^2-E)$$

Comment: Have you considered $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \delta(x-a) \; dx = f(a)$?

Comment: There seem to be a few tricks in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781464/integration-involving-dirac-delta-function

Comment: This is the integral of $p^n$ over a circle of radius $\sqrt E$ centered at the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates,

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^\infty r^n\cos^n\theta\,\delta(r^2-E)\,r\,dr\,d\theta
=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\cos^n\theta\,d\theta\int_{r=0}^\infty r^{n+1}\,\frac{\delta(r-\sqrt E)}{2\sqrt E}\,dr\\
=\frac{ E^{n/2}}2\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\cos^n\theta\,d\theta
.$$

We used the fact that $2\sqrt E\,\delta(r^2-E)=\delta(r-\sqrt E)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the the integral is zero by symmetry if $n$ is odd. Assume from now on that $n\geq 0$ is even.

One idea is to use polar coordinates $$(p,q)~=~(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta).\tag{1}$$
Then
$$I~:=~ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\! \mathrm{d}p~\mathrm{d}q~p^n~\delta(p^2+q^2-E)
~=~ \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\! \mathrm{d}r~r^{n+1}\delta(r^2-E)\int_{[0,2\pi]}\! \mathrm{d}\theta~\cos^n\theta $$
$$~=~\ldots~=~\frac{1}{2}H(E) |E|^{n/2} 2\pi \frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!}.\tag{2}$$